# How to enable SSL for a django application using Bitnami?

Tags: django, ssl, apache2, bitnami

I realize that there are so many links discussing this topic, but so far nothing in whole is working for me. I just want clear steps on how to enable SSL encryption for my project.

My requirement: all pages of the app need to be with "HTTPS" not "HTTP".

I have Bitnami djangostack-1.4.5-0 installed and for now I'm developing on my localhost port 81 so it would help greatly if I can test the redirection as well.

I already have a dummy certificate I created "myapp.crt" in the following folder with its key "myapp.key" 
C:\BitNami\djangostack-1.4.5-0\apache2\conf

After that all the links I read are confusing to where specifically I should change. Please help!! and be clear on the whereabouts of the changes.

```
myapp folder structure:
django.wsgi
manage.py
MY_APP (folder)
   |_ settings.py
   |_ wsgi.py
   |_ urls.py
   |_ _init_.py
   |_ apps (folder)
   |_ static (folder)
   |_ templates (folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by myself and thought it may help someone in the future.

```
1. Go to httpd.conf located in [BitNami_Installation]\djangostack-1.4.5-0\apache2\conf:
make sure the following is without # in front of it

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so


<IfModule ssl_module>
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

2. Go to httpd-ssl.conf located in [BitNami_Installation]\djangostack-1.4.5-0\apache2\conf\extra
make sure the following is there 
SSLCertificateFile "C:/BitNami/djangostack-1.4.5-0/apache2/conf/myapp.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/BitNami/djangostack-1.4.5-0/apache2/conf/myapp.key"
```

Note: the certificate and key are self created

```
3. In settings.py 
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE= True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

That's all for now, if some other paramter needs to be adjusted will try to add it.